# How to calculate value with 4 radio button that have different value in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have some problem about calculation using js. Here my interface.
[image]

Scenario: if i click button None the value=0, Weak the value=1, Moderate the value=2 and else it is value=3. The total will be displayed in sub_total. However, i have some problem how to create javascript for this calculation. Here my html code.

```
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',2,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_1',3,null) !!}</td>

<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',0,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',1,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',2,null) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::radio('que_2',3,null) !!}</td>
```

This is my javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $radios = $(':radio[name^="que_"]').change(function () {
        var totalPrice = $radios.filter(function () {
            return this.checked && this.value === '1'
        }).length;
        $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);
    });
    $radios.first().change()
});
```

How can i create js with 4 values ?

Comment: Is `que_1` and `que_2` ids or names? Show the rendered markup please.

Comment: que_1 and que_2 is an id

Comment: Id must be unique. That is the problem then. And you look for names with jQuery...

Comment: oh im sorry, its typo. que is names

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rendered markup looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*(I'm not used to Laravel)*

Then to sum up the values of the checked radios, the jQuery would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  // Define the total variable globally.
  var totalPrice = 0;
  var $radios = $("[type='radio']");  // Can be $("[name^='que_']") here...
  
  $radios.change(function () {
    
    // Reset total on each change.
    totalPrice = 0;
    
    // Sum up the checked.
    $("[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){  // And here, can be $("[name^='que_']:checked")
      totalPrice += parseInt( $(this).val() );
    });
    
    // Show the result.
    $('#sub_total').val(totalPrice);
  });
  
  // On load first calculation...
  $radios.first().change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_1" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="que_2" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input id="sub_total">
```